# Metro c++ async programming and UI updating. My technique?

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

The problem: I'm crashing when I want to render my incoming data which was retrieved asynchronously.

The app starts and displays some dialog boxes using XAML. Once the user fills in their data and clicks the login button, the XAML class has in instance of a worker class that does the HTTP stuff for me (asynchronously using IXMLHTTPRequest2). When the app has successfully logged in to the web server, my .then() block fires and I make a callback to my main xaml class to do some rendering of the assets.

I am always getting crashes in the delegate though (the main XAML class), which leads me to believe that I cannot use this approach (pure virtual class and callbacks) to update my UI. I think I am inadvertently trying to do something illegal from an incorrect thread which is a byproduct of the async calls.

Is there a better or different way that I should be notifying the main XAML class that it is time for it to update it's UI? I am coming from an iOS world where I could use NotificationCenter.

Now, I saw that Microsoft has it's own Delegate type of thing here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755798.aspx

Do you think that if I used this approach instead of my own callbacks that it would no longer crash?

Let me know if you need more clarification or what not.

Here is the jist of the code: 
    public interface class ISmileServiceEvents
    {
    public: // required methods
        virtual void UpdateUI(bool isValid) abstract;
    };

```
// In main XAML.cpp which inherits from an ISmileServiceEvents
void buttonClick(...){
    _myUser->LoginAndGetAssets(txtEmail->Text, txtPass->Password);
}
void UpdateUI(String^ data) // implements ISmileServiceEvents
{
    // This is where I would render my assets if I could.
    // Cannot legally do much here. Always crashes. 
    // Follow the rest of the code to get here. 
}

// In MyUser.cpp
void LoginAndGetAssets(String^ email, String^ password){
   Uri^ uri = ref new URI(MY_SERVER + "login.json");
   String^ inJSON = "some json input data here"; // serialized email and password with other data

   // make the HTTP request to login, then notify XAML that it has data to render.
   _myService->HTTPPostAsync(uri, json).then([](String^ outputJson){
      String^ assets = MyParser::Parse(outputJSON);
      // The Login has returned and we have our json output data 
      if(_delegate)
      {
         _delegate->UpdateUI(assets);
      }
   });
}

// In MyService.cpp
task<String^> MyService::HTTPPostAsync(Uri^ uri, String^ json)
{
    return _httpRequest.PostAsync(uri, 
        json->Data(),
        _cancellationTokenSource.get_token()).then([this](task<std::wstring> response)
    {
        try
        {
           if(_httpRequest.GetStatusCode() != 200) SM_LOG_WARNING("Status code=", _httpRequest.GetStatusCode());
               String^ j = ref new String(response.get().c_str());
               return j;
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) .......;
    return ref new String(L"");
    }, task_continuation_context::use_current());
}
```

Edit: BTW, the error I get when I go to update the UI is:
"An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."
In this case I am just trying to execute in my callback is

```
txtBox->Text = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are updating the UI thread from the wrong context.  You can use `task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary()` to allow you to update the UI.  See the "Controlling the Execution Thread" example in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750082.aspx) (the discussion of marshaling is at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read through and what is says is contradictory to what you suggested. From the article:
" 

    Use concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary to specify that the continuation runs on a background thread.

    Use concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_current to specify that the continuation runs on the thread that called task::then.
"

Comment: Either way, I tried both changing to arbitrary() and removing use_current(). Neither one helped with solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that when you have a continuation, if you don't specify a context after the lambda function, that it defaults to use_arbitrary(). This is in contradiction to what I learned in an MS video.

However by adding use_currrent() to all of the .then blocks that have anything to do with the GUI, my error goes away and everything is able to render properly.

My GUI calls a service which generates some tasks and then calls to an HTTP class that does asynchronous stuff too. Way back in the HTTP classes I use use_arbitrary() so that it can run on secondary threads. This works fine. Just be sure to use use_current() on anything that has to do with the GUI.

Now that you have my answer, if you look at the original code you will see that it already contains use_current(). This is true, but I left out a wrapping function for simplicity of the example. That is where I needed to add use_current().

Comment: In which video was it said that continuations would be marshaled back to the originating thread?

Comment: Here is the video. It's pretty good actually. 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/Async-made-simple-with-Cpp-PPL